# What would it be an alternative for identity server 4?

Tags: asp.net, identity, duende-identity-server

Identity server 4 will not longer be maintained after November 2022 so logically we want to move away from that. I was looking for alternatives but it seems there ain't much out there. We don't wanna go for Duende to avoid the license, same goes with AAD. Will rolling out own identity service for a single Kubernetes solution make sense?

Edit:
Maybe the question itself was not clearly stated. I know it would be possible to roll my own "identity solution", however, I am not aware of the implications of this. I would like to know if there is any other free or open source solution we could use to make this happen. If not, how hard or difficult will it be to do it on our own? I haven't found much information regarding doing this from scratch either.

Comment: The question, as it stands, is subjective. How you define "sense" here? Another question, how to actually write your own identity provider, would be fine, however, this would be more than just a single question to have a complete answer to that.

Comment: @WiktorZychla you are right, I added a clarification in an edit. Mainly I am looking for options, either if there is a framework or some free of use solution I could use.

Comment: Most components are there in the framework. Depending on details (which you miss in your question, like whether you want WS-Fed or SAML2 or OIDC), things can be easier or more difficult in .NET Framework vs .NET6. Anyway, try to ask about something specific, a general question "is it doable" has a general "yes" answer (e.g. I do it for years)

Comment: Duende has a Community Edition for companies turning over $1M USD or less : https://duendesoftware.com/products/CommunityEdition  yes they may pull the rug but its there if you want to take the risk. I rolled my own.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for free IdentityServer(duende) alternatives, I would like to suggest this article: [3 Possible Alternatives To IdentityServer](https://www.thinktecture.com/net/three-alternatives-to-identityserver/).

- [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core): open-source .NET library that helps you implement a security token service (STS).
- [Azure Active Directory (AAD) B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/active-directory/): Microsoft’s Software-as-a-Service (SaaS) identity and access management for customer-facing apps offering.
- [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/): open-source Java-based identity and access management (IAM) solution.

I think the best option in your case is [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)

Perhaps this article will be of interest to you as well:

[.NET 6.0 - JWT Authentication with Refresh Tokens](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/24/net-6-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens-tutorial-with-example-api)

> **[IdentityServer Community Edition](https://duendesoftware.com/products/CommunityEdition):**
>
> *IdentityServer Community Edition: A free license that is feature equivalent to Enterprise Edition*
>
> You can still utilize IdentityServer at no cost for:
>
> - For-profit companies/individuals less than 1M USD projected annual gross revenue and with access to less than 3M USD in capital
>   facilities.
> - Non-profit organization with a published annual budget less than 1M USD
> - Registered charities
>
> **Kindly, be aware that the license remains valid for one year, necessitating an annual renewal.**